# New to CGAL---Difficulties in Getting Started: CGAL_Qt5 Returns FALSE in CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, computational-geometry, cgal

## Background

I am relatively new to C++ and CMake and especially new to CGAL. As of now, I am simply trying to get familiar with CGAL so that I can remake an algorithm of mine that was originally built in MATLAB, but due to the inadequacy of their computational geometry libraries, I am moving to C++ and CGAL.

## System and Versions Used

OS Kernel: Ubuntu 20.04
CGAL 5.2.1
CMake 3.16.3

## Problem

I am currently trying to build the "Minimal Example Using Qt5", found [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_create_and_use_a_cmakelist.html).
At first, I was getting an error saying, `CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: No such file or directory`. This seemed to be a simple fix since the Qt folder was missing from the `/usr/include/CGAL` directory, along with others. Here, CGAL was installed with `apt-get`. To fix this I simply copied the full `include` directory from CGAL's github.
Now, I still have a problem remaining from CMake, where `CGAL_FOUND` returns `FALSE` and when I attempt to build the executable, I get no results or error messages (i.e., no `main` executable in `cgalTest/bin`).

## Further Details

### Project's Folder Structure

```
cgalTest
-bin
-build
--<CMake stuff>
-CMakeLists.txt
-doc
-include
-lib
-spike
-src
--main.cpp
-test
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(cgalTest)

### Link with Libraries ###
# CGAL
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Qt5 Core)
if(CGAL_FOUND AND CGAL_Qt5_FOUND)
  #required to use basic_viewer
  add_definitions(-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)
  #create the executable of the application
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)
  #link it with the required CGAL libraries
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Qt5 CGAL::CGAL_Core)
else()
  if(NOT CGAL_FOUND)
    message("ERROR: this program requires CGAL and will not be compiled.")
  endif()
  if(NOT CGAL_Qt5_FOUND)
    message("ERROR: this program requires CGAL_Qt5 and will not be compiled.")
  endif()
endif()
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                       Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                      Point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point>                            Mesh;

using namespace std;
// Main Code
int main()
{
    Mesh sm1;
    std::ifstream in1((argc>1)?argv[1]:"data/elephant.off");
    in1 >> sm1;
    CGAL::draw(sm1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### How I am Building the Project

I simply run the following:
`cmake --build /home/<user>/Projects/cgalTest/build`

### CMake Configuration Output

```
[main] Configuring folder: cgalTest 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -H/home/<user>/Projects/cgalTest -B/home/<user>/Projects/cgalTest/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Using header-only CGAL
[cmake] -- Targetting Unix Makefiles
[cmake] -- Using /usr/bin/c++ compiler.
[cmake] -- Boost include dirs: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include
[cmake] -- Boost libraries:    
[cmake] -- Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
[cmake] ERROR: this program requires CGAL_Qt5 and will not be compiled.
[cmake] CMake Warning at /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/cmake/CGAL/CGAL_enable_end_of_configuration_hook.cmake:99 (message):
[cmake]   =======================================================================
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CGAL performance notice:
[cmake] 
[cmake]   The variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is set to "Debug".  For performance reasons,
[cmake]   you should set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to "Release".
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Set CGAL_DO_NOT_WARN_ABOUT_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to TRUE if you want to disable
[cmake]   this warning.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   =======================================================================
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:9999 (CGAL_run_at_the_end_of_configuration)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/<user>/Projects/cgalTest/build
```

## Final Thoughts

As I have said, I am still pretty new to this and may need some hand holding during some of this. Thanks again, your help will be appreciated.
Also, do not hesitate to critique anything else you see: folder structure, coding practice, etc

Comment: Did you forget to put the braces around `${CGAL_FOUND}` and friends?  It certainly looks like it was found since I see two references to CGAL in your cmake output.

Comment: @StephenNewell They do not do that in any of the examples and as you pointed out, it did work for `CGAL_FOUND` but not for `CGAL_QT_FOUND`. I am new, but don't you use the brackets for variables, not macros? Nevertheless, I put in the brackets and it just throws a bunch of errors for "unknown arguments", as expected.

Comment: With `apt`, you want to install `libcgal-qt5-dev`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did do that. I have the following directory path: /usr/lib/qt5

Comment: Then you should have /usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h without needing to copy stuff from github.

Comment: @MarcGlisse But I did not have `/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h` and had to copy it from github. Maybe, purge all CGAL stuff and just reinstall using CGAL Source Archive?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I did another reinstall of qt5 and it works now, well atleast I am getting different errors this time. The good news is that the errors are from the build, rather than configuration of the CMake. Thanks again!

Comment: Those errors have now been fixed and the program was built successfully. Now it is is time to actually do some computational geometry! Woooohooo!

Comment: @sageedwards: Do not add SOLVED into the title. After some time you will be able to accept your answer. It will mark your question correspondigly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, when I installed qt5 I believe I used
`sudo apt-get libcal-qt5-default`
rather than
`sudo apt-get libcal-qt5-dev`.
This is of course based on my memory of what I think I did during installation, but simply running the installation for the "dev" fixed it (i.e., making `CGAL_QT_FOUND` to `TRUE` and then letting me compile).
Along with this, in main.cpp I was missing the argument definitions for `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: Please, fix the typo, so the package should be: libcgal-qt5-dev . Thanks, it works.